# Load content using AJAX on window.onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I am trying load some JSON data from a PHP backend, parse them and populate a `div` based on the JSON data I receive. I want to do this as soon as the window has been done loading.
Right now I have it setup like this:

```
$(function(){
    $.getJSON("todo_action.php?getall=true", function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

However, this approach is not working. But after the window has been done loading and I go to Chrome's developer console and run the code above, it works. Correct me if I am wrong, but I think this is not working because by default all AJAX requests are asynchronous and it has to do with the asynchronous property of AJAX, right?

I tried other variants of jQuery's built in AJAX functions like `get, load, ajax` but no avail. I have also tried making the request synchronous using `$.ajaxSetup({async: false});` and it still does not work.

Comment: Code looks fine. You did put this in `<script>` tags somewhere in the page?

Comment: Yes, that is what I did.

Comment: your code looks perfectly fine to me. It should work unless you are **Missing the closing brace ) for the DOM ready handler** which if not a typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you're not just missing a closing `);`?

```
$(function(){
    $.getJSON("todo_action.php?getall=true", function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
}); // <- here
```

It should work fine, I have an example JsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bryanjamesross/NyZeF/2/).

Comment: I didn't have this particular error, but there was some other error preventing rest of the JS code to be executed. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the page is fully loaded.

```
$(window).load(function() {
 // executes when complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images
 $.getJSON("todo_action.php?getall=true", function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the problem in my actual code. I just forgot the put the closing curly brace and the parenthesis here.

Comment: then you should accept @rossipedias answer so he gets credit, but you question was on window.load. not document.ready